# Combinations with identical values

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

First time on here, so hopefully I'm doing this right...
I'm making a math problem involving combinations, but I have identical values and now I don't know how to solve it.

When given the set, (1,3,3,5,5,5), and you want to choose 3 of the six numbers, how many combinations are there?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For a small set like this, you can just do it manually by inspection: $(1,3,3)$, $(1,3,5)$, $(1,5,5)$, $(3,3,5)$, $(3,5,5)$, $(5,5,5)$.

Comment: @Community "As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking." : **No, it isn't**.

Comment: Please ignore the *Community* comment.  It represents a **malfunctioning automated process** that is plaguing MathSE.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  Homework problems are allowed, as long as the protocol is
observed.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for showing me this! I'll keep it in mind for any future questions

Comment: @inavda Thank you so much! I know that 6 choose 3 would be 20, but this doesn't match the answer since it doesn't account for the identical values. Is there a way to calculate the number of combinations with a formula? I know that for permutations, you can divde by p!q!r!... with p, q, and r being the number of identical values, but I haven't seen anything like this for combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Not a general formula but handsome to know:

(a bit too much for a comment)

Here the coefficient of $x^k$ in polynomial: $$p(x)=\left(\sum_{r=0}^1x^r\right)\times\left(\sum_{r=0}^2x^r\right)\times\left(\sum_{r=0}^3x^r\right)=1+3x+5x^2+6x^3+5x^4+3x^5+x^6$$ equalizes the number of ways to choose $k$ numbers, and it reveals that for $k=3$ the answer is $6$.

Observe that the bounds $1,2,3$ correspond with the frequencies of the numbers $1$, $3$ and $5$ in tuple $(1,3,3,5,5,5)$.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_k$ represent the number of groups with more than k-1 elements

eg. the list (1,3,3,5,5,5) has the three groups (1), (3,3) and (5,5,5).

The number of ways to choose $3$ numbers is: $$a_3+a_2(a_1-1)+\frac{1}{3!}a_1(a_1-1)(a_1-2)$$

The total number of combinations are: $$a_3+\frac{3!}{2!}a_2(a_1-1)+a_1(a_1-1)(a_1-2)$$

For the problem above $a_1=3, a_2=2, a_3=1 $ hence total number of ways to choose 3 elements is $ \ $ 1 + 4 +1 = 6

The number of combinations is $1 + 12 + 6 = 19$

Comment: That doesn't answer the question (about choosing three...).

Comment: thank you so much!